# Android Studio jre error

Tags: java

I am trying to install Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.04. (AMD processor)

Immediately after the install command `./studio.sh` it comes back with the message:

```
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java: 6: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

Can anyone help me deal with this please?

Comment: And please [edit] your question and add the output of `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java -version; uname -a`

Comment: The above error warning is what I am asking about (i.e. the one in my question ending with ")" unexpected.

Comment: It's Android Studio 1.4. ASnd the error message was copied directly from the terminal so the one I give above is accurate.

Comment: Can I have the output of the commands above?

Comment: ./studio.sh was the command. What I got back says:
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java: 6: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java: Syntax error: ")" unexpected

Comment: o_O Open a terminal and run `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java -version; uname -a` and give me the output.

Comment: bash: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
Linux maurice-HP-ProBook-455-G1 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
maurice@maurice-HP-ProBook-455-G1:~/Desktop/Studio/android-studio/bin$

Comment: The output of `file /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java`

Comment: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB  executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=4d4d0222e883a3bf4320256278c6c0bfe14a1c11, not stripped
maurice@maurice-HP-ProBook-455-G1:~/Desktop/Studio/android-studio/bin$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have downloaded the wrong architecture for your system.

```
$ file /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=4d4d0222e883a3bf4320256278c6c0bfe14a1c11, not stripped
```

says `ARM aarch64`

```
$ uname -a
Linux maurice-HP-ProBook-455-G1 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

says `x86_64`

You need *Linux x64* and **not** *Linux ARM*.

Delete your Java installation

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_65
```

and install the right architecture...

---

To install *Oracle Java*

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To install *OpenJDK*

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Comment: But this machine has an AMD processor.  Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I am very sure.

Comment: So the code you have just sent me is the code I need to run?> (I'm not being silly about this - it's that I have had so many cockups it's getting to be a pain)

Comment: So what can I do to change it to Linux x64?

Comment: Perhaps, ... read my answer?

Comment: Well, you were right. Thanks a lot. I just wonder how they dream up all this stuff!

Comment: Great, time to accept the answer with a click at the check mark at the left side of the answer **;)**